# Child Component data as the initial value of other child Component. Passng of data between two child components

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angular project composed of a parent component and two child components. A parent is a modal while the 2 child component are panels that accept data from user/ or a form. Navigation between two child components are perform using the next and back buttons inside the parent component/modal. Now I want the data from the child 1 form component to become the initial value of the child2 component. If the user go back to first child form component and changes the form value in the child1, changes will be reflected to the child2 form initial value. I was able to pass the data from child1 form component to the parent but having a hard time passing that data from the parent component to the child 2 form as initial value. I tried passing the parent data to the child2  using patchValue inside the ngOnInit but I'm getting an error like "name is not a proprty of undefined'. Picture below shows what I really want to achieve.[image]

Code here:

```
export class Child2Component{
    @Input() person;

    child2Form : FormGroup; 
    ngOnit(){
       this.child2Form= this.fb.group({
           name: ''
       });
       this.child2Form.patchValue({
          name: this.person.name
       });
    }
```

}